# indexedDB.open() takes around 10sec on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, performance, web-applications, safari, indexeddb

I have an indexedDB database used in a web app on my iPhone.
Lately it started to take more time to start. After diagnosing this case for some time I've found that it happens because of `indexedDB.open()` running for 10+ seconds.

Here is a little code example

```
var db;
var promise = utils.promise();
var openRequest = indexedDB.open(this.dbName, this.version);

openRequest.onsuccess = function(evt) {
    db = openRequest.result;
    promise.resolve();
};

openRequest.onerror = function(evt) {
    promise.reject();
    onError(evt, 'Database open');
};
```

Database itself didn't change lately so much. Also I don't have lots of data. It has around 300 records.

Any idea how to diagnose such an issue?

**UPD** may be related https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=402980

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a result of iOS update (from 11.1.* to 11.2.*).

I have my web app added to the Home Screen. And as far as I understand when you do iOS updates the web app container is moved to a new iOS environment but conserves some features from the original iOS version (probably something related to WebView used for web app but I am not sure).

So I have added my web app to Home Screen again and it starts without delays.